# Domino Server-to-Server | Character set translation strange behavior

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

Info: We use different domino server in our environment. All server use our main domino server for mail routing (only server with external access). So all servers have set a relay host to the main server. Server all have the same version 9.0.1 FP7 installed.

Problem: When a mail is transferred from on mail.box to the mail.box from main server, strange things happen. The character set is translated and the result is a messed up mail with hieroglyphics. Good and bad Example is attached. I have tried all kind of settings in the MIME-Server configuration.

If i manually copy the mail from one mail.box to another, the email is looking OK, so it have to be a setting either in the outbound from the sending server or the inbound from main server.

Any help or tip is appreciated.

[Good Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L4iQ.png)
[Bad Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Hdk.png)

Comment: I would suggest to remove the relay host in the configuration of the other domino servers and configure mail routing via connection documents. That way the domino servers do not touch the mails but just forward them...